# HTML5 Video: Are there any benefits to using a source element over the src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

According the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-src) on the HTML5 video element, the `src` attribute is optional:

> **src:** The URL of the video to embed. This is optional; you may instead use the `<source>` element within the video block to specify the video to embed.

Is there a reason why using the `<source>` is any better or worse as an approach? Or is it literally just a different way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have different sources you need the source tag to declare them. That's not possible with the `src` attribute.

> To make it work in all browsers - use `<source>` elements inside the
>   `<video>` element. `<source>` elements can link to different video files.
>   The browser will use the first recognized format:
>
> *Sic [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp)*

Comment: Isn't it possible using javascript, detecting errors and appending the `video` tag with a new `src`?

Comment: According to MDN `Instead of the error event being dispatched to the media element itself, it now gets delivered to the child <source> elements corresponding to the sources resulting in the error.` That speaks for the `source` tag as well I guess. Perhaps it's possible but personally I prefer letting the browser handle it.

Answer (score 3):

You need the source tag if you have more than one source file (you can't have two `src` attributes). Usually you should have at least an `.mp3` and an `.ogg` version of each of your files to ensure compatibility with all browsers, so actually, you do need that source tag.

Answer (score 2):

The `source` elements allow you to define different formats using only HTML. If the first source can't be read the browser will try the next one and so forth.

With the `src` attribute you only got one shot - that is, if used in HTML.

Using JavaScript you can combine the `src` property with the [`canPlayType()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) to determine if a type of format can be played, if result of that call is non-empty then set the `src` using the link representing the file for that type. This gives you a more variety of conditional scenarios than you would get from predefined sources in html.